# Help breadboarding a circuit?

Tags: resistors, breadboard, comparator, ldr

I've been building a light based alarm system, using an LDR, Op Amp, AND gate, some resistors, and an output of buzzers..

Here's my circuit so far... It beeps when it senses light as well as being 'armed' with a toggle switch.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UOm6.png

[image]

Now I've got to breadboard that circuit, and I'm so hopeless, that it took me 25 minutes to get an LED to work :\ Is there any way I could get help breadboarding this circuit, or asking for help with a drawing on how to do it? :\

Could anyone help me put the components on this diagram? I'm really stuck, I've been failing for about 3 weeks now! :S

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoj5.png

The 741 is an 8pin and the IC2b 4081 AND gate is a 14 pin :S I have no clue, at all how I could get this to work on a breadboard, and I'd really appreciate the help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this for an assignment? Why do you think this circuit will work, and where did you get the circuit diagram from ? We could easily provide a circuit that would work but it helps to know what your requirement is. | I can see what you are trying to do BUT as shown at present it will not work as intended. | Use an LM358 (2 opamps in 8 pin package) in place of the 741 opamp. (Or an LM324 (4 opamps in 14 pin package) if you can't get an LM358). These work properly on a single battery such as you have shown - the LM741 will not. Do you have a part number for the LDR (light dependant resistor).

Comment: Before you build it, you should read up on how to use opamps correctly. (Hint: you need voltage dividers on the inputs of the opamp.)

Answer (score 5):

As well as working out what your *actual* circuit should be (see the comments to your question), your best bet would be to head on over to the [Electrical Engineering Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) where you can discuss your problems in real-time.

If possible, have a digital camera handy so you can take pictures to upload - a picture says a thousands words, after all.

Breadboarding is easy once you grasp the basic concepts.  Grasping those basic concepts, if you don't have someone to help you, can be not so basic.